# Why all the async functions seem like they are not covered branches in Jest/Istanbul coverage report?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, istanbul

I have this all over my application:
I have a well covered function, however it says "branch not covered" on `async function` part in test coverage report generated by Istanbul after running Jest test coverage script.

What does this mean? How can I cover it?

I don't understand what is **not** covered in these functions.

Test example for "getPolicyStatsAPI" function:
The rest of the functions are tested the same way. I don't believe the answer is in the test suites. But if needed I can share the rest.

```js
  describe(`API Calls`, () => {
    const mockFetch = jest.fn()
    global.fetch = mockFetch
    beforeEach(() => {
      mockFetch.mockClear()
    })
    test('getPolicyStatsAPI fetches the data and returns it as expected', async () => {
      mockFetch.mockReturnValueOnce(createAPIResponse(policySearchState))

      const response = await getPolicyStatsAPI(reqBody)
      expect(fetch).toBeCalledTimes(1)
      expect(response).toEqual(policySearchState.data)
    })
    test('getPolicyStatsAPI returns error on exception', async () => {
      const error = new Error(errorMessage)
      // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-promise-reject-errors
      mockFetch.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject(errorMessage))
      await expect(getPolicyStatsAPI(reqBody)).rejects.toEqual(error)
      expect(fetch).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    })
  })
```

Here is the code I get "branch not covered" warning on:
Branch not covered warning appears right over "async function" part of the code, and only there, as a yellow highlight.

```js
export async function getPolicyStatsAPI(reqBody: APIRequestBody) {
  const body: APIRequestBody = {
    ...reqBody,
  }
  type ExpectedResponse = { data: PolicyStats[] }
  const response = await callAPI<ExpectedResponse>({
    url: Endpoint.POLICY_STATS,
    method: 'POST',
    body,
  })
  return response.data
}
```

#### Image of test coverage report:

[image]

Comment: [Please post code as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, include the full error message, and potentially the sample of the tests you have as currently it's very hard to say what is being asked of you.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: No, I have never found the answer to this; nor the solution. Sorry @EricDS

Answer (score 1):

after leaving the comment I tried some other fixes myself, and apparently removing the `transform` key in my `jest.config.js` fixed the issue:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.test.json',
      babelConfig: 'babel.config.js'
    },
  },

  // Removed this part:
  // transform: {
  //   '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
  //   '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
  // },

  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  ..
}
```

Not sure if it's the same with your project, but you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Every async function needs an await:

```
    mockFetch.mockReturnValueOnce(await createAPIResponse(policySearchState))

    const response = await getPolicyStatsAPI(reqBody)

    expect(response).toEqual(await policySearchState.data)

    await expect(await getPolicyStatsAPI(reqBody)).rejects.toEqual(error)
```